# Why do I get error: incompatible types in assignment?

Tags: c

I am trying to read the header from a bitmap file. When I compile I get the following error; "error: incompatible types in assignment" for the line that does "bmp_header_p = bmp->header;". What am I doing wrong here?

```
struct _bmpfile {
  bmp_header_t header;
  bmp_dib_v3_header_t dib;

  rgb_pixel_t **pixels;
  rgb_pixel_t *colors;
};

typedef struct _bmpfile bmpfile_t;

bool
bmp_get_header_from_file(FILE *filename, bmpfile_t *bmp)
{
        bmp_header_t *bmp_header_p;
        bmp_header_p = bmp->header;

        fseek(filename, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        bmp_header_p = malloc(sizeof(bmp->header));

        if(14 != fread(bmp_header_p, sizeof(char), 14, filename)) {
                perror("message");
                return FALSE;
        } else {
                return TRUE;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct _bmpfile {
  bmp_header_t header;
  bmp_dib_v3_header_t dib;

  rgb_pixel_t **pixels;
  rgb_pixel_t *colors;
};
```

This "header" is not a pointer.

```
bmp_header_t *bmp_header_p;
```

This one is. The compiler is griping at you because you're trying to assign a non-pointer thing to a pointer thing. These types are different.

Looking at your code, you don't actually need or want this assignment at all, you don't even need the malloc, assuming your bmp object is already allocated by the caller:

```
bool
bmp_get_header_from_file(FILE *filename, bmpfile_t *bmp)
{
        fseek(filename, 0L, SEEK_SET);

        if(sizeof(bmp_header_t) != fread(&bmp->header, sizeof(bmp_header_t), sizeof(char), filename)) {
                perror("message");
                return FALSE;
        } else {
                return TRUE;
        }   
}
```

Comment: Indeed. If it's not really a pointer, well then add the `&` to get the address of the variable.

Comment: What would be the syntax for the caller to allocate it?

Comment: struct _bmpfile bf; (this will build one on the stack, which is fine if you're in main() or somewhere you can control the lifespan of the variable (ie., it's okay that the variable is junk when this function is done), or you should do: struct _bmpfile *bf = (_bmpfile*)malloc(sizeof(_bmpfile));

If you do the automatic version (without malloc), you'll call your get_header routine like so: success = bmp_get_header_from_file(file, &bf);  otherwise you'll do (bmp_get_header_from_file(file, bf); since bf will be a pointer

Comment: You may want to spend some time making sure you really understand the different possible allocation strategies here, though, or you will surely have more trouble down the line. I recommend you Google "c memory management" and read as much as you can find, then discuss it with someone knowledgeable and then read some more 'til it makes sense.

Comment: I tried the first syntax and got the following "error: variable has incomplete type 'struct _bmpfile'
        struct _bmpfile bf = (_bmpfile)malloc(sizeof(_bmpfile));"

Comment: Err, try bmpfile_t there.  And that should be bmpfile_t *bf = (bmpfile_t *)malloc(sizeof(bmpfile_t));

Comment: Same error with bmpfile_t, that is just a typedef of _bmpfile.

Comment: Are they in different modules? (different files?) You'll need your struct _bmpfile definition to be in a shared header both can see, in that case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32601/discussion-between-effervescent-phantom-and-crowder)